# How to efficiently determine percentage of particular character in each block of 100 characters in a string?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of a particular character within each 100 block substring of any given string of arbitrary length. I have a working version shown below, but the given string can potentially be very long - 10s of thousands to millions of characters.

The string will consist of no more than 8 different characters: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H.

I need to scan each 100 character block and determine the percentage of the given character within that block. If the percentage is more than a determined amount, the block index is recorded. I'm finding it hard to explain what a '100 character block' is. I don't need to split the string in to 100 character chunks, I need to start at each character and read the next 99 characters, then repeat for each character until the end. Like, read [0..99], [1..100], [2..101], [3..102], [4..103] and so on.

I'm currently brute forcing the calculation but it is fairly slow. Is there a clever way of making this more efficient?

```
def calculate_percentage_errors full_string, searched_character, percentage_limit 
# full_string:        ABCDGFGEDCBADDEGDCGGBCDEEFGAAAC.......
# searched_character: A
# percentage_limit:   0.5

n = 0 
error_index = []
while n < (full_string.length - 99) do
  #grab the string 1..100, 2..101 .... 
  sub_string =  full_string[n..(n+99)] 

  # determine the number of characters in the string
  character_count = (100 - sub_string.gsub(searched_character, '').length)

  if (character_count/100.0) > percentage_limit
    # record the index if percentage exceeds limit
    error_index << [(n+1),(n+100)]
  end

  n += 1
end

return error_index
end
```

Comment: @IvayloPetrov: That should be an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `each_char` and an index to look behind as characters leave the block:

```
def calc_errors string, char, threshold
  errors = []
  count = 0

  string.each_char.with_index do |c, i|
    count += 1 if c == char
    count -= 1 if i > 99 and string[i - 100] == char
    if i >= 99
      if count > threshold
        errors << [i - 99, i]
      end
    end
  end

  errors
end
```

Unlike the other answers, which could visit characters 100 times, this algorithm visits each character only *twice*: once when entering the block and once when leaving.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as mine, although maybe your implementation looks nicer :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the count from the previous block. It is changed with at most 2. Let me give an example for that. If you have `5` occurrences of `A` in the block `2..101` and you want to compute the count for `3..102`, you can simply check if at position 2 you have an A and if on position `102` you have an `A`. If you have an `A` on `102`, but not on `2`, for example, the count will be `6`. You need to see three more cases. Using this it will be much faster I believe.

Here is some sample code:

```
def calculate_percentage_errors full_string, searched_character, percentage_limit                                                                                         
  count = full_string[0..99].count(searched_character)                                                                                                                    
  error_index = []                                                                                                                                                        
  error_index << full_string[0..99] if count / 100.0 > percentage_limit                                                                                                   

  1.upto(full_string.length - 100).each do |index|                                                                                                                        
    count -= 1 if searched_character == full_string[index - 1]                                                                                                            
    count += 1 if searched_character == full_string[index + 99]                                                                                                           

    error_index << full_string[index, index + 99] if count / 100.0 > percentage_limit                                                                                     
  end                                                                                                                                                                     

  error_index                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

Comment: Good suggestion, Ivaylo, but no +1 until you provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check at each index position.

Suppose the error limit (full string length times percentage limit) is *n*, and you get *m* counts for the character `A` within substring at position `[i, 100]`. If *m* is smaller than *n*, then you can skip the index so that the next index to check would be `[i + (n - m), 100]` because for any *j* such that:

*i < j < i + (n - m)*, ........................................... (1)

the maximum count of `A` in `[j, 100]` is *m + (j - i)* (which happens when no character in `[i...j]` is `A` and all characters in `[i + 100...j + 100]` are `A`). And since from (1),

*m + (j - i) < n*,

we know that the count for `A` in `[j, 100]` is smaller than *n*.

---

Considering this fact, the algorithm can be improved as follows:

```
def calculate_percentage_errors full_string, searched_character, percentage_limit 
  limit = (full_string.length * percentage_limit / 100.0).to_i
  error_index = []
  i = 0
  while i < (full_string.length - 99) do
    margin = limit - full_string[i, 100].count(searched_character)
    if margin > 0
      i += margin
    else
      error_index << [i + 1, i + 100]
      i += 1
    end
  end
  error_index
end
```

Comment: Same problem as the other answers: `full_string[i, 100].count` completely undoes the efficiency of sliding the block since it revisits characters that were in the previous block.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that your algorithm steps differently. However I can't get your code to work for any percentage limits other than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Please treat this as an extended comment. (No upvotes please; downvotes grudingly accepted.) This is merely one way to implement the algorithm @Ivaylo suggested.

Edit: Just as I was about to post, I saw that @Ivaylo had come though with an implementation.  I'll post this anyway, as an alternative formulation, but again, please treat it as a comment to his answer.

**Code**

```
def bad_blocks(str, contents, block_size, max_pct_per_block)
  nbr_blocks = str.size-block_size+1
  return nil if nbr_blocks < 1
  max_per_block = max_pct_per_block.to_f * block_size / 100.0 
  # g[c] is the number of times c appears in the first block
  g = block_size.times.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k|h[k]=0}) {|i,g|g[str[i]]+=1}

  # Enumerate blocks
  (nbr_blocks).times.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |b,h|
    contents.each_with_object([]) { |c,a| h[b] << c if g[c] > max_per_block }  
    g[str[b]]            -= 1 
    g[str[b+block_size]] += 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "ABCCDCEEAFFFGAGG"
bad_blocks(str, 'A'..'G', 5, 40)
  #=> {1=>["C"], 2=>["C"], 7=>["F"], 8=>["F"], 9=>["F"], 11=>["G"]}
bad_blocks(str, 'A'..'G', 5, 20)
  #=> {0=>["C"], 1=>["C"], 2=>["C"], 3=>["C", "E"], 4=>["E"], 5=>["E"],
  #    6=>["E", "F"], 7=>["F"], 8=>["F"], 9=>["F"], 10=>["F", "G"], 11=>["G"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to search for several (different) characters in the same block of 100 char, you may want to do it in one single swoop:

```
def chars_in_block(block)
  result = Hash.new(0)
  block.each_char { |c| result[c] += 1 }
  result
end
```

This will give you back an Hash that could can then filter according to your rule. It will garantee you only make one single pass.

Comment: This will visit each character 100 times, since the blocks overlap.

Answer (score 0):

To have a array window of 100 characters, you can use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) from `Enumerable` mixin. So instead of

```
while n < (full_string.length - 99) do
  sub_string =  full_string[n..(n+99)] 

  # .. your code ..

  n += 1
end
```

You do this

```
full_string.each_char.each_cons(100) do |sub_string|
  # .. your code ..
end
```

As it only uses iterators, it should be more memory-efficient and faster.

If you need an index (for the `error_index`), you can use [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) from `Enumerator` class.

Here is your code rewritten

```
def calculate_percentage_errors(full_string, searched_character, percentage_limit)
  # full_string:        ABCDGFGEDCBADDEGDCGGBCDEEFGAAAC.......
  # searched_character: A
  # percentage_limit:   0.5

  error_index = []
  threshold = (percentage_limit * 100)
  count = nil
  full_string.each_char.each_cons(100).with_index do |sub_string, index|
    # count searched characters the first time, then adjust as characters are read
    if count.nil?
      count = sub_string.count(searched_character)
    else
      count += 1 if sub_string.last == searched_character
    end

    # record the index if percentage exceeds limit
    error_index << [index + 1, index + 100] if count > threshold

    # adjust count
    count -= 1 if sub_string.first == searched_character
  end
  return error_index
end
```

**Edited: updated answer to count each character only 2 times, as @Max suggested**

Comment: `each_cons` is an efficient way to get the consecutive blocks, but you still end up counting each character 100 times as the block shifts.

Comment: @Max You are right, the counting could be avoided. As the OP was struggling with reading '100 characters blocks', I found it a good opportunity to use `each_cons`.

Comment: @Max updated answer. I stick with `each_cons` for demonstration purpose but I prefer your solution: more readable and simpler.